# How to transfer a complex C struct to C from Go

Tags: c, go, cgo

I am writing gobinding for a private project

there is a `typedef struct` like this.

```
typedef struct {
skynet_risk_t risk;
.....
const void *unknown[13];
} skynet_result_t;
```

when I try passing this struct into a func 
`skynet_status_t skynet_classify(
......,
skynet_result_t *result);`

I write like this

```
result := C.skynet_result_t{}
status = C.skynet_classify(
    ...
    &result,
)
```

I got this
`cannot use _cgo2 (type *_Ctype_char) as type unsafe.Pointer in argument to _Cfunc_skynet_classify`

but when I write a func like this

```golang
void print_skynet_result(skynet_result_t *result){
    // do nothing
}
```

and I call it in same way.

```
result := C.skynet_result_t{}
C.print_skynet_result(&result)
```

compile through and everything is ok.
what's the trouble I encountered

I don't know why cgo say it is a `(type *_Ctype_char)`

Comment: Are you sure the offending parameter is the `&result` and not e.g. the `req`? Generally you can wrap an unsafe.Pointer() around a pointer in order to cast it. Be especially careful when passing strings, which usually must be cast via C.CString() - https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/

Comment: @user2089648 Wow man What you said is a reminder for me, the line cgo compile error may not correct !! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

the compiler always said

```
./skynet.go:266:14: cannot use _cgo2 (type *_Ctype_char) as type unsafe.Pointer in argument to _Cfunc_skynet_classify
```

the line is error …… I never thought about this.

the origin func define like this.

```
skynet_status_t skynet_classify(skynet_request_t *req,
skynet_classify_type_t type,
const void *data,
size_t length,
skynet_result_t *result);
```

and I define a wrapper like this one.

```
func (s *skynetRequest) Classify(t uint32, data []byte) (*skynetResult, error) {
    var result skynetResult
    // var temp = C.pass_skynet_result_t((*C.skynet_result_t)(&result))
    var status = C.skynet_classify(
        (*C.skynet_request_t)(s),
        (C.uint)(t),
        unsafe.Pointer(&data[0]),
        C.ulong(len(data)),
        (*C.skynet_result_t)(&result),
    )
    if status != 0 {
        return &result, errors.New("classify error")
    }
    return &result, nil
}
```

@user2089648 reminded me, this may not cause by result parameter, but may cause by other parameter，then I find the `const void *data` should be transfer like this
`unsafe.Pointer(&data[0])`，wrapper works well.